# What configuration change read only task of log files

Tags: linux, configuration, jboss, read-only

What configuration changes required in jboss-server standalone.xml file for generating read only server log.

Jboss server runing on linux machine.

Can I achieve read only task on changing xml configuration or not.

If you have any idea can you advice me to achieve the read only task of log files.

Comment: why would you want a read only log?

Comment: Do you mean that the logs should be unmodifiable to anyone (except the server of course, it must be able to write the logs of course)?